# What is your enterprise Python package governance approach?

Tags: python, security, enterprise

What are the common approaches to enterprise python package management? In my career I have encountered organisation that are on the lower end of the risk appetite scale and often create governance restrictions for developers.

Some organisations have a hesitation to allow developers to freely access and incorporate pypi python packages into their code base or production environments without some "vetting" in place. In this situation what would the best strategy be to ensure that no malicious packages are Incorporated into a codebase?

Answer (score 0):

Big corporations usually tend to define policies that need to be enforced across the dev teams. Sometimes the policies define exact security measures to be implemented, so knowledge of the policy and the requirements before one acts is a must.

Having said that, I recall to have seen projects and clients who used following:

1. A list of allowed and disallowed libraries held in an Excel file. If something is on the list - it's fine. If something isn't, either don't use or go speak to a higher-up architect to include the library. If you use a library that is not on the list in you productive code you are not compliant and needs to fix it. (I know, this soft approach sounds like a disaster, but in practice it isn't. Usually developers tend to use libraries because they save time and deliver functionality, not because they are willing to have their employer hacked, so handling small incompliances tend to cost less time than what you see below).
2. Create a repository containing only the libraries that are allowed. Make the dev teams use the repository only. It's a bit more restrictive version of 1. The drawback is that it needs to be maintained a lot and rather quickly so it contains all latest library versions. I'm not an expert with python, but it looks fairly easy to me: https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/. Something you could manage with one Apache instances and a bit of scripting.

The good thing about point 2 is that companies usually tend to have some kind of caching proxy already. I recall how one of the companies have been banned by Maven, because the developers have been killing the repository with requests that were not cached. So there should be already something there that one may build the solution upon.